# How to run tests (coverage) for multiple packages in Go?

Tags: go

Project Structure:

```
-MakeFile
-DockerFileForLogging
-DockerFileForMonitor
-Logging
   -go files
   -go.mod 
-Monitor
   -go files
   -go.mod
```

When I try to generate and run test on this project, I get Main module does not contain package /*/**/.../Logging.

Command :

```
    go test -race -coverprofile=coverage.out ./logging/...
    go test -race -coverprofile=coverage.out ./monitor/...
```

Tried multiple commands but I keep getting different errors.

Comment: did you mean to say multiple modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `...`, I believe the correct one would be `*`

Like the example:

```
go test -race -coverprofile=coverage.out ./logging/*
go test -race -coverprofile=coverage.out ./monitor/*
```

In this documentation you can get some details to understand better.

https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm